# Identical type mismatch in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the snippet below from a code where `rdd` is `RDD[(String,Vector)]`, but unfortunately my Scala compiler is complaining with the error `Type mismatch, expected: RDD[(String,Vector)], actual: RDD[(String,Vector)]` where I call `flagVectorOutlier(rdd, predictedRDD)`

```
def someFunction() {

  testData.foreachRDD( rdd => {
    val vectorsRDD = rdd.map( pair => pair._2 )

    val predictedRDD = model.latestModel().predict( vectorsRDD )

     flagVectorOutlier( rdd, predictedRDD )
  } )

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}

def flagVectorOutlier(testVectors: RDD[(String, Vector)], predicts: RDD[Int]): Unit = {

}
```

Considering the actual and expected types are the same, what is the wrong point here? How could I solve this issue?

Comment: What's your imports look like?

Comment: @LionelPort I'm using these imports: `import org.apache.spark.SparkConf`
`import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD`
`import org.apache.spark.streaming._`
`import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext`
`import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors`
`import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans`

Comment: What happens if you add that type specifier to the foreachRDD( rdd: RDD[(String,Vector)]... ?  Are those Java String and Vector classes?

Comment: @n0741337 I tried to add to `rdd` but it didn't work. In this case Vector is from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg`

Comment: Maybe you're colliding on scala.collection.immutable.Vector and the Apache version?  Trying specifying the full import name in the function def type declaration.

Comment: @n0741337 thank you for your help! I could overpass the error. I'd like to let registered here the solution. As you told, I modified `testVectors` argument signature to `testVectors: RDD[(String, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]` and it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Search for "scala rename import" if you don't want to use the full import path everywhere for the Apache Vector class.

Comment: @SauloRicci What version of Spark and Scala you are using ?

Comment: @n0741337 consider adding that as a solution so that the question can be accepted

Comment: @SachinJanani I'm using Spark 1.2.0 and Scala 2.11.5

Answer (score 1):

I've got this kind of error before. 
It happened when I was using a java library which would use `java.util.List`, while my own code was using `scala.collection.immutable.List` and I mixed them up.

You can have two classes with the same name coexist in code easily, but the error message will not display fully-qualified names, so I would get `Type mismatch, expected: List[Integer], actual: List[Integer]` which seems puzzling. The solution is just to fully qualify the types of your input parameters or use typeDefs to distinguish them.

---

Bonus: I've also had a similar problem with tuples. For instance, when a method can either expect tuples or direct params:

`def f(param: (Integer, String))` versus `def f(param1: Integer, param2: String)`

When calling the method with the wrong parameters (say, 2 params instead of a tuple), on a cursory inspection the error message can seem to show two identical types. This gets worse if you have several nested tuples (thus too many parentheses but the same types).

Comment: Thank you! In my case, this was actually because I was working through the "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" course by Martin Odersky ([link](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004)) and the "List" class defined in previous lectures had overwritten the `scala.collection.immutable.List` built-in.

Thanks again!